# Migrate search from 2010 to 2013

Tags: search, migration

I'm in the middle of a 2010 Enterprise to 2013 Enterprise migration, I've successfully restored all custom solutions, content, BDC, UPS etc. but now sure how to migrate search (we're not using FAST)

I had a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483.aspx and it says "The following service applications have databases that you can upgrade during this process:" and Search is listed

However for the other services I restore the dbs and then use the names when creating the service, with search I need to use PowerShell to specify the database name `New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -DatabaseName` but if I select the restored 2010 admin database it will complain that it is not empty (I suspected it would do that)

Essentially we only use SP search for people (so far) with lots of custom metadata properties coming from various system, I wish to not have to remap these with the UPS

Best way to migrate SP2010 search to SP2013 without recreating and mapping metadata properties?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Restore command instead of New. here are the steps i want to mention:

- Backup the Search Service Application admin database from SharePoint
  2010 environment and restore on SharePoint 2013 database server,
  preferably by the name as "Search Service Application_ AdminDB"
- Now, login to your SharePoint 2013 App server, and create the
  application pool to be used in Search Service Application

  New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name SPSearchServiceAppPool -Account "DOMAIN\USER"

  $appPool = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity "SPSearchServiceAppPool"
- Now connect to local Search Instance and Create a New Search Service
  Application by suing the restored admin DB

  $searchInst = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -local
  Restore-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Name "Search Service Application" -applicationpool $appPool -databasename "Search Service Application_AdminDB" -databaseserver "SP2013DB_P_ALIAS" -AdminSearchServiceInstance $searchInst
- It will take some time 5-10 mins to get this completed

[DEAD LINK - Migrate SharePoint 2010 Search Service Application to SharePoint 2013 - The Fineprints](http://akforsharepoint.blogspot.com/2014/10/migrate-sharepoint-2010-search-service.html)

Comment: Perfect thanks, did a bit of searching but most hits described how to create a new one